# Cannot create Oracle user with specific password

Tags: oracle11g, user-management

In Oracle I tried this query

```
create user ACT_APP 
    identified by password 
    profile APP_PROFILE 
    default tablespace TS_MODULE_D 
    temporary tablespace TEMP;
```

after sending this query
and i got these 2 errors.

1. password verification for the specified password failed
2. Password should contain at least one digit, one character and one punctuation

So I modified my query to

```
create user ACT_APP 
    identified by !234qwer 
    profile APP_PROFILE 
    default tablespace TS_MODULE_D 
    temporary tablespace TEMP;
```

But I got another error

> missing or invalid option

Comment: Try with the punctuation in another place than first, it could have special meaning, and possibly you need quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the manual:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_8003.htm#SQLRF54737)

> Passwords must follow the rules described in the section "[Database Object Naming Rules](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#i27570)"

`!234qwer` is not a valid object name because of the leading `!` therefor it needs to be enclosed in double quotes:

```
create user ACT_APP 
    identified by "!234qwer"
    profile APP_PROFILE 
    default tablespace TS_MODULE_D 
    temporary tablespace TEMP;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    create user ACT_APP 
    identified by qwer@123 
    profile APP_PROFILE 
    default tablespace TS_MODULE_D 
    temporary tablespace TEMP;
```

If not, try changing the password and try